# Flex shrink not working on img as flex item

Tags: css, image, flexbox

I just noticed that somehow image elements inside a flex container don’t seem to shrink, and I cannot figure out why.

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg" width="332" height="332" alt="">
  <img src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg" width="332" height="332" alt="">
</div>
```

It seems to work well with `flex-grow`, but not with `flex-shrink`. Why is that?